# Updating a bundle in Felix embedded into Android application shows: "java.io.FileNotFoundException"

Tags: android, osgi, bundle, apache-felix, osgi-bundle

I am embedding Apache Felix into an android application. Starting and stopping the bundles work fine. But I would like to update a bundle by reading another bundle file. Here's my code:

```
bundle1 = bundleContext1.installBundle("file:sdcard/Download/AndroidImageViewer_1.0.0.201308221559.jar");
            bundle1.start();
            bundle1.stop();
            try {
                bundle1.update(new FileInputStream(new File("file:sdcard/Download/AndroidVideoPlayer_1.0.0.201308231205.jar")));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            bundle1.start();
```

I expected this to work, and that my bundle will get updated, but unfortunately, I got the following error:

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:sdcard/Download/AndroidVideoPlayer_1.0.0.201308231205.jar (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:239)
```

This exception occurs at the following line:

```
bundle1.update(new FileInputStream(new File("file:sdcard/Download/AndroidVideoPlayer_1.0.0.201308231205.jar")));
```

I am totally sure that the bundle `AndroidVideoPlayer_1.0.0.201308231205.jar` exists in the Download directoy, and I tried to start it previously and it worked fine. I am confused. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: are you sure the url should not start with file://sdcard/...

Comment: Yes I am sure. Actually, your way didn't work even for starting the bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you are creating a File object from a URL!

```
 new File("file:sdcard/Download/AndroidVideoPlayer_1.0.0.201308231205.jar"))
```

Try this

```
 File file = new File( "sdcard/Download/AndroidVideoPlayer_1.0.0.201308231205.jar" );
 context.update( new FileInputStream(file));
```

Or

```
 context.update( new URL("file:sdcard/Download/AndroidVideoPlayer_1.0.0.201308231205.jar").openStream());
```